# How to get VALUE of mat select

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a mat select and I want to get the value of the dropdown that user selects. How can I do this? ALso if the user changes the value by reselecting how can I capture that also.
Html code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
              <select matNativeControl formControlName='country' (change)="selected($event)">
                <option disabled>Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let option of country" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
              </select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Typescript Code:

```
country = ['au', 'kr', 'gb'];
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

Check this sandbox : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1k7ykb-cfmaq7?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts

ngModel binds the value of the select picker with the one in TS file. You don't need a separate change handler for that

In your HTML

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let o of arr" [value]="o">{{o}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
 <div> Seleced: {{selected}}</div>
```

In you TS file using your array( we can even set the default value)

```
export class SelectValueBindingExample {

  selected: string;

  arr: string[] = [];

 constructor() {
    this.arr.push("au");
    this.arr.push("kr");
    this.arr.push("gb");
    this.selected = 'gb';
  }
}
```

Comment: @ahmed did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Select as **matNativeControl** you have to use the native

> (change)="handler($event)"

EventHandler. The Material Event *selectionChange* wont work here. Of course you could just use Angulars reactive-forms approach but for simple use cases (e.g. you just have one select field) thats enough.

In your implementation file:

```
handler($event): void {
    console.log('selected value:: ', $event.target.value)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**(selectionChange) and MatSelectChange are well designed for this purpose.**

html:

```
<select formControlName='country' (selectionChange)="getSelected($event)">
... your options
</select>
```

ts:

```
getSelected(event: MatSelectChange): void {
  console.log(event.value); // get selected value
  console.log(event.source); // get all source options
}
```